# How to convert .xls file to pdf through python scripting

Tags: python

I have created .xls using xlwt module.
Now i want to convert this newly created xls file to pdf. Can anyone please tell me how can i do this through python scripting. Am using python 2.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possibilities here: either you read the `.xls` back in as cells and generate a PDF, or maybe you want to print the `.xls` to `.pdf` from the program that just created the `.xls`.

In the first case you might want to consider writing the `.pdf` directly (you have the data to make the `.xls` in the program at some point). I have a grid class that can be written out in HTML format, or to `.xls' (using`xlwt`),`.xlsm`(using`openpyxl`) and to`.pdf`(using`reportlab`).

You will need to use the second option if you write formula and that kind of stuff in your `.xls` and want to have the calculated results in your `.pdf`. In that case use subprocess to call `Microsoft Excel` or `OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc` with the right commandline parameters for printing/converting the file to PDF.

E.g. for LibreOffice 4.0 the commandline would be:

```
scalc --convert-to pdf yourfile.xls
```

which will result in a `yourfile.pdf`

Comment: For Microsoft Excel conversion from .xlsx to .pdf what is command line   will be ?